# x509store.Certificates.Find passing in string variable for object find value gives no match but hardcoded string value does

Tags: c#, asp.net, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I have an issue where when I am debugging the following code with a string variable passed into the Certificate.Find method, I get no match:

```
string thumbprint = "1243583953004";
X509Store store = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation);
X509Certificate2Collection certColl;
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
store = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
```

But when I put a breakpoint and run the method with the hardcoded string value, I get a match:

```
store = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "1243583953004", false);
```

Am I missing something here? The second parameter of the find method is an object type.

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. There was some sort of control code in the variable that I was not able to see. After copying and re-pasting the value, I fixed this issue.